# Using ML.Net Console Model in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, ml.net

Please help to solve this problem. I have created a asp.net web application. Also I have ML.net console model that predicts results. Is there a way to join these two things together?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the model from the console project using `mlContext.Model.Save` and in the ASP.NET application you can use the [`PredictionEnginePool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net#register-predictionenginepool-for-use-in-the-application) to use the model.

Comment: like jon said, save the model from the console and load the same in the asp.net application. So that the loaded model can be used for predictions